# How do I get the smell of Febreeze (uncomplexed cyclodextrin composition) out of my carpet?

Tags: alcohols, hydrogen, organic-oxidation, smell

Help! I sprayed my old carpet, which had gotten a little mildewy from some wet towels left on it, with Febreeze original scent. Now I can't get that horrible scent out! It might also be mixed with some newly formulated Nature's Miracle which I sprayed on the couch above the carpet at the same time, but I don't know the chemical formula for that.

I have  tried the following: white vinegar in water, vodka in water with some grapefruit essential oil, bleach solution in water, Concrobium Mold Control spray (I can still smell the sour mildewy smell...or is that the vinegar?), ZEP Mold Stain and Mildew Stain remover, Folex carpet spot remover, baking soda, corn starch, vacuumed up the last two as best I could...

So my question is, what next? Hydrogen peroxide? Isopropyl alcohol? Unscented dishwashing detergent? I don't want to layer on any more scents, god forbid, in an attempt to get rid of this fake flowery sour smell. (Someone described the Nature's Miracle scent as making their cat smell like "candy-coated skunk." I think the Febreze might have bonded to the Nature's Miracle...)

I would enjoy understanding the science of this too!

My research so far online says that Febreeze cyclodextrin is cup shaped and surrounds smelly organic molecules, but doesn't break them down. And the scent that's added to the cyclodextrin is re-released through heat, so steam isn't recommended. And I'm a renter and I doubt my landlords will replace the carpet.

Thanks!

Annette

Comment: Test chlorine bleach on a hidden spot of the carpet and wait a few days to be sure the material is unaffected. If so, then test a *dilute* solution of chlorine bleach on a cloth with the horrid scent, to see if it improves things, or makes it worse, before tryin it on the carpet itself.

Comment: Waiting for a cast iron pan seasoning one :)

Comment: Do not use chlorine bleach products here! While possibly effective the chloro-organics are not something you want to have permanently around. However, percarbonate based products (those other chlorine-free products) may work here and you may be able to live, at least longer-term, with the results. A dry path, ozone or singlet oxygen, but there are short term toxicity concerns.

Comment: Alchimista: One could actually try a small surface area cast-iron source (the anode) and lots of activated carbon (cathode) in an electrolyte of baking soda and H2O2. Logic: one-electron reduction of H2O2 forms hydroxyl radicals which convert to carbonate radicals (from .OH + HCO3- = H2O + .CO3-) that are good at breaking down organics. You could forget the Fe/Carbon galvanic cell approach and just use UV light on the H2O2/NaHCO3, or B-12/ZnO in H2O2/NaHCO3 in strong sunlight also.

Comment: One should test all my recommendations on small areas first to determine both effectiveness and correct exposure time. Note: Overdoing the latter could progressively remove coloration (as in bleach) the carpet also.